# Solving advanced complex inequalities

Tags: complex-numbers

$|z − 2| + |z + 2| ≤ 2$

I've tried solving it like this:

$|x+iy - 2| + |x+iy + 2| \le 2\\
|x - 2 + iy| + |x + 2 + iy| \le 2\\
\sqrt{(x-2)^2+(y)^2} + \sqrt{(x+2)^2+(y)^2} \le 2\\
\sqrt{(x-2)^2+(y)^2} \le 2 - \sqrt{(x+2)^2+(y)^2}\\
\sqrt{x^2 - 4x + 4 + y^2} \le 2 - \sqrt{x^2 + 4x + 4 + y^2}\\
x^2 - 4x +4 + y^2 \le 4 - 4\sqrt{x^2 + 4x + 4 + y^2} + x^2 + 4x + 4 + y^2\\
-8x \le 4 - 4\sqrt{x^2 + 4x + 4 + y^2}\\
-2x \le 1 - \sqrt{x^2 + 4x + 4 + y^2}\\
-2x - 1\le\sqrt{x^2 + 4x + 4 + y^2}\\
4x^2+4x + 1 \le x^2 + 4x + 4 + y^2\\
3x^2-y^2 \le 3$

Which seems to be incorrect, what am I doing incorrectly in my procedure? Is my logic correct?

Comment: I can see one wrong step here: From $-2x-1\leq \sqrt{x^2+4x+4+y^2}$ we cannot deduce the inequality for their squares, that you have written. An example:  $-10 \leq 3$ but $100\not\leq 9.$

Answer (score 0):

Solve the inequality geometrically.

Since $|z-w|$ is the distance between the points representing $z$ and $w$, the inequality $$|z − 2| + |z + 2| ≤ 2$$ can be interpreted as:

*The sum of distances from $z$ to $2$ and from $z$ to $-2$ is smaller than $2.$*

Put on $x$-axis $-2$ and $2$ and various points $z$ in the plane .... wherever is $z\in \mathbb{C},$ the sum of distances to $2$ and $-2$ is at least $4,$ obtained when $z\in [-2,2].$